I am using salesforce Apex language to do my work. I am using apex class containing functions I want to hit a function using the button on opportunity
I am having an apex class with multiple methods but I want to hit its 1 method on click a button on opportunity.
I had tried different ways but failed to get where to place my button and how to execute my method using button.
I tried this javascript onclick function code like
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}  {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}  sforce.apex.execute("CreateLocationInRadius","createLocation",{"oppId":'{! Opportunity.Id }'});

You shouldn't use the "apex.js" library, the JavaScript buttons made this way are considered old school and dangerous in Lightning Experience. And you'd need to bump the API version up anyway, v30 is going to be turned off.
You'll need a bit of custom UI code, whichever you're most comfortable with. Visualforce, Aura or (if you have proper dev tools like VSCode) LWC.
If you're after a "just do something, no UI, no choosing options, just run" I guess best would be https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions-headless.html. If you actually do want the user to choose something or display anything fancier than just success/error message - normal quick action: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-quick-actions-screen.html
As for how to call Apex from LWC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-call-imperative.html should be a good start?
Consider going through the self-paced training Trailhead modules? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components for example
